# passing a parameter to remote modal in bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, parameters

I have a function to load remote content into a bootstrap 3 modal, which uses the id from a php generated recordset.
I seem to be retrieving the id correctly, but the remote page content always shows the first id i clicked on

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.pull-right').click(function(){
        var id = this.id;
        alert(id);
        $('#myModal').modal({

    remote: '/member_profile.php?MemberID='+id,
    show: true
});
    }); 
});
</script>
```

As the id is being generated correctly, is the parameter not being passed to the remote php page correctly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reset the data any time you open an AJAX modal. This is what you're looking for:

`$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '#myModal', function() {
  $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
});`

Comment: Awesome !
Been going round in circles on this.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function(){
   $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
});
```

Yes, "hide" not "hidden" if you did not disable the Modal animation by default. This will perform more stable and solid since it fires right after you dismiss the modal div. I just do this way after a really nightmare...

And I found that removeData('bs.modal') has already been added into the Bootstrap 3.1 source code, but just on event 'hidden.bs.modal', so sometimes the bug still happens.