# Bootstrap 3.1.0 modal remote content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

After a bit of trial and error, I got a remote modal window loading and destroying content with bootstrap 3.0.1

[passing a parameter to remote modal in bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21457365/passing-a-parameter-to-remote-modal-in-bootstrap-3)

here is the code snippet

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.pull-right').click(function(){

    var theid = this.id;

    //Open modal window passing the member id as a parameter        
    $('#myModal').modal({
    remote: '/plugins/mission/councilmember_popup.php?MemberID='+theid,
    show: true
    });
    //Destroy modal window content on close, otherwise parameter will be retained       
    $("#myModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $(this).data('bs.modal', null);
    });
});
```

});

I have now installed 3.1.0 and now realise that the remote modal no longer works, I get the modal background, but can't see the modal window

Can't seem to find any examples of remote content in 3.1.0, cananyone point to an example

Answer (score 0):

Think I have the answer...

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<!-- Modal content comes from the page in the href -->
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

    </div>         <!-- /modal-content -->
</div>     <!-- /modal-dialog -->

</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

is the syntax for the main page

```
<div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
             <h4 class="modal-title">Title</h4>
        </div>            <!-- /modal-header -->
          <div class="modal-body">
                        ...
          </div><!-- /modal-body -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>            <!-- /modal-footer -->
```

is the syntax for the remote content